# Compute the L2 distance at once using matrices and vectors

Tags: matrices, python

I have to implement the L2 distance, which has the geometric interpretation of computing the euclidean distance between two vectors. The distance takes the form:

$$d_2(I_1,I_2)=\sqrt{\sum_{p} \left( I^p_1 - I^p_2 \right)^2}$$

If $I_1$ has a size of `(50000 x 3072)` and $I_2$ a size of `(3072)`.

I have to implement that distance using Python with Numpy, and I don't have to use loops. I have to do it using only multiplication and two broadcasting sums.

My problem is that I don't know how multiplication and broadcasting sums can do it. Maybe using $I_2$ transpose and multiply it to $I_1$, but I'm only guessing.

Is there a way to get `L2 distance` using matrix multiplication?

**UDPATE.**

I think, but I'm not sure, I can use:

$$(x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy$$

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, $I_1$ is a matrix but $I_2$ is a vector, how are you defining a distance between two objects that don't live in the same space? Is it that each row of your matrix corresponds to a different vector that you want to compute its distance from $I_2$?

Comment: @Rammus $I_1$ are 50000 vectors of size 3072.

Answer (score 0):

If I1 has shape (50000 x 3072) and I2 has shape (3072):

```
temp = I1 - I2 # substract I2 from each vector in I1, temp has shape of (50000 x 3072)
temp = temp ** 2 # do a element-wise square. temp has shape of (50000 x 3072)
temp = temp.sum(1) # do a sum on the second dimension. temp now hasshape of (50000,).
```

Then temp is your L2 distance.